# Pygame - Como resolver efeito fantasma da imagem

Tags: python, pygame

Estou fazendo uns testes no pygame e criei um "personagem" que se movimenta, porém ele cria um efeito fantasma na tela. Gostaria de saber como resolver.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Essa terra é o que seria o personagem)

O efeito fantasma que eu me refiro é q quando movimento, o personagem "anda", porém maio que é criada uma "copia" dele(como mostra a imagem)

O código vou colocar do a parte de movimento:

```
class playerA(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    velocidade = 20
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.ImagemPlayer = pygame.image.load("dirt.png")

        self.rect = self.ImagemPlayer.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = largura / 2
        self.rect.centery = altura - 60
    def colocar(self,sup):
        sup.blit(self.ImagemPlayer, self.rect)

def main():
      while sair != True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sair = True
            if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT :
                    player.rect.left -= player.velocidade
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT :
                    player.rect.right += player.velocidade
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP :
                    player.rect.top -= player.velocidade
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN :
                    player.rect.top += player.velocidade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Este "erro" ocorre porque não há a atualização da tela ao fim do seu loop principal:
`while sair != True`, onde o pygame gerencia os eventos de seu jogo.
Lembre-se que cada iteração do loop desenha na tela os objetos adicionados no seu `display.blit`. Portanto como não há gerenciamento interno destas particularidades, já que o pygame é uma reimaginação das aplicabilidades da biblioteca SDL(Uma poderosa biblioteca em C de controle multimídia e multiplataforma) é sua responsabilidade limpar o buffer atualizando a tela e as posições de seus novos eixos em cada "re-draw".

Re-desenhe sua tela de background antes de adicionar seus demais elementos:

`pygame.display.blit(fundo, (0, 0))`

onde `pygame.display` é sua variavel de background e `fundo` seu preenchimento. (seja uma cor, uma imagem...)

Depois, adicione:

`pygame.display.update()` ao final do seu loop e seu problema deverá ser resolvido.

Um adentro em seu código, há uma redundância na cláusula do seu laço `while` principal, já que como o "evento" interno `for event in pygame.event.get()` já deveria corresponder ao fechamento da aplicação, a condição do seu laço while se torna desnecessária e portanto, estás desperdiçando memória em seu jogo criando uma variável inutilizada.

```
from sys import exit
...
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type is QUIT:
            exit()
```

Caso deseje algum comportamento adicional em um "pós morte", encapsule estes comportamentos em um método e os chame dentro do laço `for` antes do exit(), é uma recomendação pessoal apenas, deixando cada parte com suas responsabilidades, melhorará muito em futuras expansões e manutenções de seus projetos.